# importing spss data set to python.String variables and date variables are not getting pulled into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, spss

There was a problem by loading the spss data into the python.The variables are coming as object data type rather than their primitive spss data type.A variable is having date format but while loading it is considering some raw value,and also variables with string data type are converted to object data type and not displaying the proper values.I have used the following code.

Thanks in advance!

```
"rawdata = list(spss.SavReader((bm+'empdata.sav'),
                     returnHeader=True,
                     recodeSysmisTo=99,
                     selectVars=x,
                     verbose=True,
                     rawMode=False,
                     ioUtf8=1,
                     ioLocale="english"))

# creating a pandas dataframe
exp_data=pd.DataFrame(rawdata)
exp_data=exp_data.rename(columns=exp_data.loc[0]).iloc[1:]"
```

Comment: `object` `dtype` is correct and expected behaviour, for datetimes you may need to convert using `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: how are you exporting from spss?  note that pandas can read sas/stata/excel files, so if spss can output any of those, that might be an easier way to transfer the data -- but as always you'll want to double check that the conversion worked as expected